# Adding users outside of CP or front-end registration form

Tags: users

Is there a simple / best practice way for creating new users programatically? My specific use case involves capturing user data for online sales using a 3rd-party form with Stripe integration. When a user checks out and makes the purchase (not on the Craft site), I'd like to capture the data and generate a user account automatically *on* the Craft site.

My current idea, which should work, is to trigger Zapier to write a custom record (containing the user fields) to the MySQL database directly. I've done it before in other contexts but am curious if there's a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a [custom plugin](https://pluginfactory.io) that exposed a [anonymous controller](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/controllers#allowing-anonymous-access-to-actions) endpoint that accepted to the user info you want to save.

From there the controller endpoint could create a new UserModel, populate necessary fields/properties you want to save, then call [`craft()->users->saveUser()`](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/UsersService#saveUser-detail) and let Craft do the database populating.

Comment: Thanks Brad. Sounds like the smarter way is to do through the Craft `saveUser()` action, versus writing to the db directly.

Comment: It's probably the way I'd go.